# How do I check whether a value is present in any of several rows with the same ID in R?

Tags: r

I have a large (550k x 200) data frame that contains information on incidents and actors. Multiple actors can be involved with an incident, and I am trying to create an incident-level data frame with information about whether any actor has a certain attribute.

A reprex would be:

```
incident <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B")
actors <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
attribute <- c("red", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "red")
df <- data.frame(cbind(incident, actors, attribute))
```

My goal is to have a dummy variable indicating whether each incident involved a red actor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) Base R**  Put a + in front of ave if you want 0/1 instead of logical.

```
transform(df, red = ave(attribute == "red", incident, FUN = any))
```

**2) dplyr**  Put a + in front of any if you want 0/1 instead of logical.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(incident) %>%
  mutate(red = any(attribute == "red")) %>%
  ungroup
```

**3) data.table** Put a + in front of any if you want 0/1 instead of logical.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[, red := any(attribute == "red"), by = incident]
```

**4) sql**  This returns a red column of 0/1 values.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select *, max(attribute = 'red') over (partition by incident) red 
  from df
  order by rowid")
```

### Note

The cbind in the defition of df should be removed since it will coerce the numeric column to character.  With the code below it retains its original class.

```
incident <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B")
actors <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
attribute <- c("red", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "red")
df <- data.frame(incident, actors, attribute)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I created the reprex, I realized what I needed to do. I am sharing it here in case it helps anybody else.

The simplest solution I could come up with was.

```
ddply(df, .(incident), summarize, Red = "red" %in% attribute)
```